# Implication for linear dependence

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove that if a set of vectors is linearly independent, then something happens. I want to show that if that set is linearly dependent, then that something doesn't happen.

So suppose $V = \{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ are linearly dependent.

I know that two vectors are linearly dependent if one is a scalar multiple of the other and that the set $V$ above is linearly dependent if some linear combination of the vectors with nonzero scalars gives the zero vector.

Can I claim that if $V$ is linearly dependent, then there exist some $v_i, v_j$ such that $v_i = cv_j$? Does this follow from the above standard definition of linear independence for a set with more than 2 elements?

Comment: No. One vector need not be a scalar of another in a linearly dependent set. Also, (linear dependence) $\implies$ (something) is not equivalent to showing (linear independence) $\implies$ (something).

Comment: This almost never works outside of a set of size 2. For instance, take the set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $S = \{\hat{e}_1, \hat{e}_2, \hat{e}_1 + \hat{e}_2\}$. You can't have a linearly independent set of size $3$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ($S$ is linearly dependent) and no pairs of vectors satisfy your listed property.

Answer (score -1):

Nope.

As @Ethan commented, take the example $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$. The third is the sum of both, but clearly none of them is a multiple of the other.

Comment: This is the exact example I posted above.